# Format flex items based on wrap state

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I am using Flexbox for following layout and willing to switch to CSS Grid or plain old floats if I can achieve my goal. This questions is very similar these two: [detect flex wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012428/how-to-detect-css-flex-wrap-event) and [select an item based on wrap state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580851/which-css-selector-can-be-used-to-select-a-flex-box-item-in-wrapped-state).

If my viewport has enough space to fit two flex items side by side, my second flex item should be right aligned.

[image]

If there isn't enough space, then my second flex item will wrap. But, as that happens, I want to change text alignment from right to left.

[image]

Comment: Not possible. CSS can't detect wrapping.

Comment: That's what media queries are for. Flex containers aren't aware of children wrapping. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276