# CSS Flexbox - Select Every Item which is at the beginning of a newline (Wrap)

Tags: css, flexbox

is there something like a wrap-line selector in css?

Im using CSS-Flexbox for a layout with the wrap option.

I do not know how many lines I have beforehand but at every 
newline (every wrap) the pseudo selector "before" should NOT insert 
content. Else it should insert some content.

Here is an example of the problem im facing:
Just copy this code into JS-Fiddle:

```css
.items {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item:first-of-type:before {
  content: '';
}

.item:before {
  content: '\01F354';
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item A
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item B
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item C
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item D
  </div>
</div>
```

My aim is that in the second line for the first item should not be a burger icon.

Comment: You will need Javascript for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28371650/css-flex-last-and-first-item-in-a-row-selector, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28580851/which-css-selector-can-be-used-to-select-a-flex-box-item-in-wrapped-state

Comment: No css doesn't have what you mean, it can't detect a new line like so. Need javascript, or modify html a bit, like manually setting wrapping divs with a certain width. Unless number of items for each line is always the same and they're static, then you can use :nth-of-type(<number_here>);

Answer (score -2):

this maybe helpful

you can set width for items  and

use 
:nth-child() selector and  set item flex-basis:

but it is better for you to use JavaScript or from server side

add `title` class on items to hide icons

```css
.items {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.25rem 0.5rem;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-basis:75px;
}

.item:first-of-type:before {
  content: '';
}

.item:before {
  content: '\01F354';
}

.item:nth-child(4n+1):before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    item 1
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 2
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 3
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item 4
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item A
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item B
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item C
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    item D
  </div>
</div>
```